# How do conditionally thread in a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, multithreading

My website's api works fine and runs fast, except for one route.  Since nodejs is single threaded, we wanted to make the api call DATA be separately threaded so that it doesnt block the rest of the incoming calls, and because it took too long to fork.  Basically the code I want is like this:

```
router.get(req, res){
    if(MasterThread){
        create a thread to run the DATA functions
    }
    else{
        res.json(getDATA())
    }
}
```

is this possible at all? All the tutorials I found implied that I either had to use cluster, or my threading had to occur in my main.js, neither of which I want to do.

When I tried to set up the threading across 2 files, the imports for nodejs threading were always null, or my imports never worked.

So again, if this a possible thing?

Comment: You should spawn the secondary thread on the root of you application, outside route definitions, the way you're doing right now is spawning a new thread every time the route is called, this is costly, Node has to load all the modules from a cold-start, if your API is called, let's say, 100 times in a second, this will become an issue. Think the worker thread as another Node API running, it should be started one time and then wait for input.

Comment: Could you post the code for the route that doesn't work properly? Network I/O won't block other code waiting to be executed by the event loop if you're doing async properly.

Comment: Could you please describe which things are performed during the route ?
Based on your answer we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `worker_threads` for this case I use it for one of my sites and it works perfectly here is minimal example

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')
const worker_script = path.join(__dirname, "./worker.js")

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
              const worker = new Worker(worker_script, {
                workerData: JSON.stringify(obj)
              })
              worker.on("error", (err) => console.log(err))
              worker.on("exit", () => console.log("exit"))
              worker.on("message", (data) => {
                console.log(data)
                res.send(data)
              })

    })
```

and here is the worker

```
const { parentPort, workerData, isMainThread } = require('worker_threads')

if (!isMainThread) {
     console.log("workerData: ", workerData)
      //do some heavy work with the data
    var parsed = JSON.parse(workerData)

    parentPort.postMessage(parsed)

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This makes the most sense!